# ImageMagick and Paperclip on Rails only accepts bmp file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm trying to set up a rails app with paperclip and ImageMagick on Ubunutu 10.10, I have managed to make it work but only with bmp files, when i try to upload any other kind of file I get the error:

```
Image Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError
Image Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError
```

I thought it had something to do with ImageMagic so I found this old tutorial

http://www.randycullom.com/chatterbox/archives/2006/12/installing_imag.html

So I uninstall ImageMagick, installed jpg,tiff and png libraries, on jgp library I used

./configure --enable-shared
...

And then install ImageMagic with configure

./configure --enable-lzw=yes --enable-shared=yes --disable-static --without-perl
make
sudo make install

and the error still apears, on my enviroment.rb I have

Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"

Which is the path than running 'which convert' gave me, on gem file:

gem "paperclip", "~> 2.3"
gem 'rmagick'

What am I missing? Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On Ubuntu, you can usually safely intall ImageMagick via apt-get (or aptitude). Normally I do:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
sudo apt-get install libmagick9-dev [deprecated]
sudo gem install rmagick
```

**Edited**

use instead of libmagick9-dev

```
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat
```

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: I needed to install some other packages.
Too make it work @ Ubuntu 14.04:
sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev

Answer (score 7):

Update from @bartuzz comment

**Ubuntu 14.04:** 
        sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev

Answer (score 7):

Following on from the other answers (@Callmeed, @arturtr), for Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat
sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```

worked for me, but installing rmagick without the sudo

```
gem install rmagick
```

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 16.04:

`sudo apt-get -y install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev`